# For loop is not iterating through all of the items in a list

Tags: python

I am currently creating a python script for a coding puzzle (advent of code) and the goal of the puzzle is to remove numbers from a list that meet certain criteria. The problem is my for loop only iterates through 3 of the 4 items in the list.
Code:

```
def count(data, target_bit):
    zero_count = 0
    one_count = 0
    for numbers in data:
        if numbers[target_bit] == '0':
            zero_count += 1
        else:
            one_count += 1
    return [zero_count, one_count]

current_list = ["1001", "0001", "1111", "0011"]
oxygen_list = current_list
current_index = 1

zero_count = count(current_list, current_index)[0]
one_count = count(current_list, current_index)[1]

if zero_count > one_count:
    loop_count = 0
    for items in current_list:
        print(loop_count)
        if items[current_index] == "1":
            oxygen_list.remove(current_list[loop_count])
        loop_count += 1
        

print(current_list)
```

Comment: do not modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: Can you share the full code, and/or explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just added the full code

Comment: Also the goal of the puzzle is to iterate through a large list of binary numbers, and look at the first bit of all of them, and then remove all the numbers that have the least common bit in that position

Comment: Is "least common bit" the same as "least significant bit"?

Comment: yes it is. 1-most_common_bit is a solution for that. You don't have to calculate anything

Comment: For example if you have the list : [0001, 1110, 0101] and you only look at the bits in the first position, there are Two zero bits and One 1 bit making 1 the least common bit

Comment: Also in the real puzzle there are over 1000 binary numbers, this is just a small scale test

Answer (score 1):

This should be rule one of modifying lists: **never remove items from a list while you're iterating over that list**.

Instead, you can construct a new list and omit the items that don't fit:

```
if zero_count > one_count:
    new_list = []
    for items in current_list:
        if items[current_index] == "0":
            new_list.append(items)
    current_list = new_list
```

You can do this more compactly with a list comprehension:

```
if zero_count > one_count:
    current_list = [items for items in current_list if items[current_index] == "0"]
```

---

P.S.: I noticed you call `count` twice, and throw away half of the results each time. Instead, you can do this:

```
zero_count, one_count = count(current_list, current_index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if items[current_index] == "1":
    oxygen_list.remove(current_list[loop_count])
```

this right here is removing the item where the 2nd number is 1

comment out these lines and you will see it will iterate over all 4 items in the list